# Python, Username and Password with 3 attempts

Tags: python

I have started learning python about 2 weeks ago and am trying to create a password system that can store multiple usernames and passwords. I am trying to add a bit of code where it makes you wait a minute if you input a wrong password 3 times.

I keep on getting an error where if you get the password wrong 3 times and wait the 60 seconds, even if you do input the right password and username it prints "Your password is wrong. You have only 3 attempts left."

Can somebody help and point out flaws that I have in the code?

```
import time
username = ["Test","Test2"]                 
password = ["1Ac!","2Bd!"]
success = 0
Tries = 0
Valid = False                                            
Pass = ""
    
            
def login():                                                    
    global success
    global Pass                                                 
    global Tries
    inuser = input(str("Enter your username: \n"))
    inpass = input(str("Enter your password: \n"))
    if inuser not in username:
        print("username not found in directory")
        login()                                                   
    else:
        posUser = username.index(inuser)
        Pass = password[posUser]                                 
        while success != 1:
            if Tries == 3:
                print("You have had too many attempts. Wait 60 seconds before trying again")
                for i in range(60, 0, -1):
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print(i)
            if Tries == 3:
                Tries = 0
                inuser=str("0")
                inuser=str("0")
                login()
            else:
                break
    if Pass == inpass:
        success=1
    else:
        Tries += 1
        AttemptsLeft = (3 - Tries)+ 1 
        print("Your password is wrong. You have only {} attempts left.".format(AttemptsLeft))
        login()
        

        
login()
if success==1:
    print("Welcome to ------")
```

Comment: Your pairing of usernames and passwords is only implicit, in that `username[i]` has `password[i]`. You can make that more explicitly, for example with something like `accounts = [("Test", "1Ac!"), ("Test2", "2Bd!")]` or `accounts = {"Test": "1Ac!", "Test2": "2Bd!"}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get rid of the recursion, everything will get simpler.

```
import time
username = ["Test","Test2"]                 
password = ["1Ac!","2Bd!"]
success = 0
Tries = 0
Valid = False                                            
Pass = ""
    
            
def login():                                                    
    global success
    global Pass                                                 
    global Tries                                     
                            
    while success != 1:
        inuser = input(str("Enter your username: \n"))
        inpass = input(str("Enter your password: \n"))
        if inuser not in username:
            print("username not found in directory")
        else:
            posUser = username.index(inuser)
            Pass = password[posUser]         
        if Tries == 3:
            print("You have had too many attempts. Wait 60 seconds before trying again")
            for i in range(60, 0, -1):
                time.sleep(1)
                print(i)
            Tries = 0
            inuser=str("0")
            inuser=str("0")
        if Pass == inpass:
            success=1
        elif Pass != "":
            Tries += 1
            AttemptsLeft = (3 - Tries)+ 1 
            print("Your password is wrong. You have only {} attempts left.".format(AttemptsLeft))
        

        
login()
if success==1:
    print("Welcome to ------")
```

You should also consider getting rid of the `global` variables. Instead, return values using `return`.

```
import time
username = ["Test","Test2"]                 
password = ["1Ac!","2Bd!"]
success = 0
Tries = 0
Valid = False                                            
Pass = ""
    
            
def login():                                                    
    success = 0
    Pass = ""                                          
    Tries = 0                                  
                            
    while success != 1:
        inuser = input(str("Enter your username: \n"))
        inpass = input(str("Enter your password: \n"))
        if inuser not in username:
            print("username not found in directory")
        else:
            posUser = username.index(inuser)
            Pass = password[posUser]         
        if Tries == 3:
            print("You have had too many attempts. Wait 60 seconds before trying again")
            for i in range(10, 0, -1):
                time.sleep(1)
                print(i)
            Tries = 0
            inuser=str("0")
            inuser=str("0")
        if Pass == inpass:
            return True
        elif Pass != "":
            Tries += 1
            AttemptsLeft = (3 - Tries)+ 1 
            print("Your password is wrong. You have only {} attempts left.".format(AttemptsLeft))
        

        

if login():
    print("Welcome to ------")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code needed some refining. I also made a timer for stopping. Also, you should use `getpass` library to not show the password.

```
import time
import getpass
username = ["Test","Test2"]                 
password = ["1Ac!","2Bd!"]

Tries = 1
    
            
def login():  
    global Tries  

    print("\n----------------- Login -----------------------\n")                                                
    inuser = input("Enter your username: ")
    inpass = getpass.getpass("Enter your password: ")
    if inuser not in username:
        print(f"User {inuser} was not found.")
        login()
    else:
        xindex=username.index(inuser)
        passw=password[xindex]
        
        if inpass==passw:
            
            return True
        else:
            if Tries==3:
                print("\nToo many attempts. Please wait for 60 seconds.")
                for k in range(x,0,-1):
                    b=f"Time left: {k} Seconds"
                    print(b,end="\r")
                    time.sleep(1)                
                Tries=0
                login()
            else:
                Tries+=1
                print("\nWrong Password or Username.")
                login()
x=login()
if x:
    print("Welcome to ---------")
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have provided the solution, I will try to provide the reasoning:

This is because of the recursion in line number 38 where you're calling the login function after setting Tries=0.

When the recursive call is made, the compiler puts the rest of the statements below it on hold (you can imagine all the below statements pushed to a stack to be executed later). The program counter now goes to the start of the function: Where you'll enter the right username and password, therefore it sets the success variable to 1. Now that your function has completed, the compiler had a set of pending statements before remember?

It goes and executes them. But in there, the value of the variable **inpass** is still the old, incorrect one and that is why it prints out Wrong password. You can understand this by printing out inpass just before the line

```
if Pass == inpass:
```

TlDr; Get rid of the recursion